# How can i use Apache Wicket to process multiple model instances on a single form?

Tags: arrays, hibernate, model-view-controller, wicket

I am using Wicket to generate a form to allow users to set values for several model objects.  Each model object has two fields, `operNam` and `slaNam`.  The list of `operNam` values is taken from a parameter string `operationNames` and I split this space-separated list as shown below and put each one into an ArrayList called `myListResult`.

```
String result = parameters.getString("operationNames");
        //split list
        ArrayList<String> myListResult = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(result.split(" ")));
        for (String word : myListResult) {
            System.out.println("===>" +  word);
        }
```

What I want to do, is create a form for the user with two elements for each entry in `myListResult`.  I am adding a `TextField` containing the value of each operation name in `myListResult` and an empty `TextField` to allow the user to enter values for `slaNam`.  The code I'm currently using to do this is below:

```
for(String operation : myListResult) {
    form.add(new TextField<String>("operNam" , new PropertyModel<String>(operation, "operNam")));   
    form.add(slaNam);
}
add(form);
```

The problem I have is that the above code is adding `TextField`s with an `id` value of `operNam` for each item in `myListResult` and this is throwing an error due to duplicate `id` elements in the html.  I also tried doing it as follows:

```
for(String operation : myListResult) {
    form.add(new TextField<String>(operation , new PropertyModel<String>(operation, "operNam")));   
    form.add(slaNam);
}
add(form);
```

This avoids the problem of duplicate `id` elements but causes a problem because now my form elements don't map to my model object which expects a field called `operNam` and another called `slaNam`.

**My Question is**

How would I create form elements that represent an arbitrary number of models without using duplicate element `id` names.

Heres a image of how I would want the html to look if I had 4 items in `myListResult`:
[image: example of page for 4 elements in <code>myListResult</code>]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use a `Repeater` to add your `TextField`s. For example a `ListView`

```
ListView listview = new ListView("listview", list) {
    protected void populateItem(ListItem item) {
        item.add(new TextField("textField", item.getModel()));
    }
};
```

With approriate HTML:

```
<span wicket:id="listview">
   <input wicket:id="textField" type="text"></input><br/>
</span>
```

To use multiple fields in each row, the easiest solution is to use objects that contain these fields:

```
public class MyRow
{
    public String slaNam;
    public String operName;
}
```

And create a `List` of them:

```
List<MyRow> myRows = new ArrayList<>();
```

And use this list in the `ListView`

```
ListView<MyRow> listview = new ListView("listview", myRows)
```

You can use this in the `populateItem`

```
 protected void populateItem(ListItem<MyRow> item) {
        item.add(new TextField("slaNam", new ProperyModel(item, "slaNam")));
        item.add(new TextField("operName", new ProperyModel(item, "operNam")));
    }
```

Or, use a `ProperyListView` for even less code :)

Comment: Hey I edited the question so hopefully it sounds a bit clearer

Comment: Did you understand my answer? Or lookup the wicket documentation on repeaters? You will need a list of objects. That object can contain a slaNam and operNam. If you make them public or provide getters and setter, you can simply use them with PropertyModel on itemModel.